# Convert Day name to Date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have at table with Column names

```
Pattern ={Monthly,Weekly,Daily}
Days_of_Week={Monday to Friday} => multiple values allowed.
```

example(table)

```
task_id, pattern, Reminder_days_before, days_of_week 
      1, weekly ,                    2, monday;tuesday
```

Now to get convert these daynames(days_of_week) to date based on the current_date().

Say for example if the current_date is 05/13/19 then the days_of_week should be converted to '05/14/19;05/20/19'.

Comment: Don't store delimited data. It's not normal.

Answer (score -1):

You can do `GETDATE() +1`, `GETDATE() +2` and so on to get future dates and then extract days (if you want to) from them by doing `EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)` to get the future days.
Also, it is not a good idea to store the delimiter separated values in a column. You can probably create another table named `days_of_week` and store `(task_id, day_of_week)` pairs in it which will have many-to-many relationship.